# without an event for a radiobutton or checkbox, how can I set it true or false programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, radio-button

I have a page with radiobuttons and checkboxes; the form has previously been filled out by the user.  I need to bring the form back up for them to edit the EXISTING data, which means I have to programmatically check checkboxes and check radio buttons.

If I HAD an event, I could easily change the corresponding control with srcElement, but there is no event in this case.  I haven't been able to find a way with document.getElementById('XXX'). ???  to work in any way.

Using Angular 4 if that helps.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance, :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data binding. Then you can set the changed value and the checkbox and radio buttons will check/select automatically.

Here is an example:

```
                    <label>
                        <input id="sendCatalogId"
                               type="checkbox"
                               [(ngModel)]="sendCatalog"
                               name="sendCatalog" >
                        Send me your catalog
                    </label>
```

And a radio button:

```
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" id="addressType1Id" value="home"
                                       [(ngModel)]="addressType"
                                       name="addressType">Home
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" id="addressType1Id" value="work"
                                       [(ngModel)]="addressType"
                                       name="addressType">Work
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" id="addressType1Id" value="other"
                                       [(ngModel)]="addressType"
                                       name="addressType">Other
                            </label>
```

This in the component class:

```
...
export class CustomerComponent  {
    sendCatalog = false;
    addressType = "home";

    constructor() {
        sendCatalog = true;
        addressType = "work";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Oh, a much better answer than I came up with though similar ..
   I added [checked]="boolean component variable here".
What I learning from your answer is that the binding to a boolean is enough ... the [checked] piece didn't need to be there.
Thanks Deborah.

Comment: But the addresstype must be "other" or "work" or some such, right?

Comment: In my example, yes.

Comment: I'm struggling with the chkbox example, I copied it from your example and pasted it in.
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
    <input id="sendCatalogId"
           type="checkbox"
           [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="sendCatalog"
           name="sendCatalog" >
    Send me your catalog
"): ng:///HomeModule/HomeComponent.html@7:11
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:19746:34)

 Typescript complains about ngModel too ... that's strange am I missing an import or something?

Comment: Duh... even if I don't use forms,(which I don't), I have to import FormsModule and then all is well.  Sorry for the additional comments.